# Namespace não funciona corretamente / BC30002: Tipo 'prod' não está definido

Tags: asp.net, asp, namespace

fui convidado a resolver um problema em sistema de um cliente em asp.net (Linguaguem na qual não domino).
Sem mais delongas...

Meu arquivo produto.aspx tem a seguinte diretiva

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitefeito.Mkraeprod" %>
```

algumas linhas abaixo tenho esta outra:

```
Dim Component as new prod()
```

Ao qual retorna o seguinte erro:

> BC30002: Tipo 'prod' não está definido.

Não entendo o porque, pois no mesmo nível de arquivo prod.aspx tenho vb/addproduto.vb

que contém:

```
Namespace Sitefeito.Mkraeprod
Public Class prod
```

Como tentativa de solução:

No arquivo web.config (na raiz do projeto) adicionei

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="Sitefeito.Mkraeprod" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
```

Como visto neste tutorial: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/importing-namespaces-into-razor-views-in-asp.net-mvc-3

Porém sem sucesso

Comment: Tentou fazer assim? Dim Componente as new  Sitefeito.Mkraeprod.prod()

Comment: Sim, infelizmente nada! O problema surgiu depois que fui forçado a mudar a migra do Windows 2003 pro Windows 2007. Visto a falta de suporte da minha revenda.

Answer (score 1):

Como o problema surgiu com a mudança de versão do servidor, verifique como está a compilação do MVC no projeto, qual o framework e se as referências para o MVC estão ok na solução. Qual a versão do MVC?

Se comentar essa página ou excluí-la da compilação, o projeto todo funciona normalmente? É um problema pontual?

Se não houver as referências no projeto a aplicação vai procurar no GAC do servidor e talvez não encontre a versão que precisa.